# popViewController:animated: not working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios9

I am using a subclassed UINavigationController which manages all the viewControllers in my app. It pushes and pops viewControllers in the main flow and presents and dismisses modally those viewControllers which are required arbitrarily.

In one case, I need to present a viewController modally before popping another in the main flow, like so:

```
//Called in custom UINavigationController subclass
[self presentViewController:searchVC animated:YES completion:^{
    [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; 
}];
```

The above code used to work without a hitch till iOS 8, and does not work in iOS 9. The same viewController as before remains when the presented vc is dismissed.

Also, this is being logged in the console:

```
popViewControllerAnimated: called on <CustomNavigationController 0x7d846600> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
```

This was never an issue till now, especially since the popViewController method is called in the completion block.

Could this be a bug?

Any solution/suggestion/workaround is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrapping the popViewController call in an `dispatch_async` block worked.

```
[self presentViewController:searchVC animated:YES completion:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }); 
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work for me in a standard `UINavigationController`, even though you get a "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" warning. The following code replacing `popViewControllerAnimated:` gets rid of that warning.

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[viewControllers removeLastObject];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = [viewControllers copy];
```

So I would guess the problem lies within your subclass. Do you override `presentViewController:animated:completion:` or `popViewControllerAnimated:`?

Comment: No, I don't override these methods. I was able to fix the problem by calling popViewController in a dispatch_async block. However, a message with "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" now gets logged

Comment: The code I posted in my answer should fix that problem. It also probably does not need the `dispatch_async` wrapper.

Comment: It seems highly unsafe to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I noticed this problem too in iOS 9.
I changed the code to (Swift):

```
controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

where "controller" is the presenting VC instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using split view controller, try removing it.